# Using Google Analytics to make a Poll based on link clicks

Tags: html, image, google-analytics

So I know google analytics can track my page links, but how can I get the number of clicks as raw data and reincoorporate it into the HTML?

I have two images in anchor tags, the user can "vote" for either image a or image b. Each image leads to its own separate html page. How can I use the pageview data from each of these two links and display them underneath the images on the main page, essentially creating a poll.

Comment: You should consider writing your own script to do this, it would be much much easier than trying to use Google Analytics for something it wasn't intended for. PHP/ASP.NET/RoR/Javascript

Comment: You could use database or text file for this, to store number of views for each image?